# How to reshape pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm following along in the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow". In it, there is a section on Time Series Forecasting. I'm interesting in applying the methodology to intraday stock index price data.
My data looks like this:

```
In [229]: frame.tail()
Out[229]: 
               O        H        L        C         Day      Time
1472543  4017.50  4018.39  4013.52  4014.38  2022-05-13  15:55:00
1472544  4014.68  4018.05  4014.68  4017.20  2022-05-13  15:56:00
1472545  4017.13  4019.95  4017.01  4019.83  2022-05-13  15:57:00
1472546  4019.86  4021.55  4017.94  4021.32  2022-05-13  15:58:00
1472547  4021.21  4024.77  4020.72  4023.56  2022-05-13  15:59:00
```

For each day there are 390 "observations" and there are 3751 days. I would like to reshape this data to the form: (3751, 390, 4).

The reason being that the data in the book has the shape: (7000,50,1). Based on this, it would be easiest to apply the methodology from the book to my dataset if my data were in the same shape.

However, I have tried several different ways (for several days now) without any luck.

I've tried making a `numpy.array()` of the dates (3751) and one for the times (390) and one for the price values (i.e. each day would have the shape (1,390,4)).
This however did not work:

```
In [255]: c = []

In [257]: c.append(frame["Day"].unique())

In [258]: c.append(frame["Time"].unique())

In [259]: c.append(frame[features])

In [273]: np.array(c, dtype=object).reshape(3751,390,4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-273-ddd7578e8519> in <module>
----> 1 np.array(c, dtype=object).reshape(3751,390,4)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3751,390,4)

In [248]: x = np.array([frame["Day"].unique,frame["Time"].unique(),frame[["O","H","L","C"]]], dtype=object)

In [249]: x.shape
Out[249]: (3,)

In [250]: frame["Day"].unique().shape
Out[250]: (3751,)

In [251]: frame["Time"].unique().shape
Out[251]: (390,)

In [252]: frame[features].shape
Out[252]: (1462890, 4)

In [253]: 390 * 3751
Out[253]: 1462890

In [254]: features
Out[254]: ['O', 'H', 'L', 'C']
```

Comment: Why not try something like `frame.values.reshape((3751, 390, 4))`?

Comment: Pandas dataframes are always two-dimensional, although if you extract only the four data columns and convert to a numpy array, you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: @pavel I think that'd need to be `frame.iloc[:, :-2].values...` or `frame[features].values...`

Comment: if you could link the csv file that would be helpful

Comment: In the end how should your data look like?

Comment: `df.assign(Time = df.groupby('Day')['Time'].cumcount()).pivot('Day', 'Time')`

Comment: @pavel:  In [274]: frame.values.reshape((3751, 390, 4))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-274-f7c10a4d805d> in <module>
----> 1 frame.values.reshape((3751, 390, 4))

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8777340 into shape (3751,390,4)

Comment: @onyambu, so close!   In [276]: x = frame.assign(Time = frame.groupby('Day')['Time'].cumcount()).pivot('Day', 'Time')

In [277]: x.shape
Out[277]: (3751, 1560)

Comment: @wjandrea, that totally worked!! :-D If you put that into an answer I can accept.

Comment: Great! Really it was @pavel who came up with it though, I just fixed it.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Don't put the solution in the question itself, that defeats the purpose of the Q&A format. As well, you need to [give proper credit](/help/referencing). What I would do instead is post an answer (yes, [you can answer your own question](/help/self-answer)) and include links to the comments and author's names (pavel and me). You could even make the answer a community wiki if you really wanted to avoid taking credit for it. (For comparison, [here's an answer I posted like that](/a/72062525) and [another](/a/70385448).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the comments, @pavel provided: `frame.values.reshape((3751, 390, 4))`

and @wjandrea provided: `frame.iloc[:, :-2].values...` or `frame[features].values...`

The latter worked like a charm:

```
frame[features].values.reshape((len(days), 390, 4))
```

where `days` here is an array containing all full, non-holiday trading days.